# Cannot resolve gem dependency

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

I can't seem to get this dependency to resolve. I've tried setting the versions in the Gemfile explicitly, but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts?

```
Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate activemodel-3.2.8, because builder-3.1.3 conflicts with builder (~> 3.0.0)
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `activate'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:51:in `block in require'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:50:in `each'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:50:in `require'
```

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
source :rubygems
source :gemcutter
source :rubyforge

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 2.4'
gem 'mongo', '1.6.2'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.5'
gem 'builder', '~> 3.0.0'
gem "mongoid-history"
gem "mongoid-rating"
gem "mongoid_vote"
gem "geocoder"
gem "slim"
gem "sidekiq"
gem "sprockets" #required by sidekiq for some reason...
gem "logger"
gem "carrierwave"
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
gem "mongoid-history"
gem "airbrake"
```

Comment: Have you tried using `gem 'builder'` instead of `gem 'builder', '~> 3.0.0'`? You are intentionally limiting the version of your gem and this is what's causing problems

Comment: Yes, I have, adding the 3.0 was an attempt to resolve it. I switched it back to `gem 'builder'`, ran `bundle update` and once again, `Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate activemodel-3.2.8, because builder-3.1.3 conflicts with builder (~> 3.0.0)`

Comment: Try `bundle update` after deleting your `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: I've also tried `bundle update builder` and get this: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "builder":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (>= 0) ruby depends on
      builder (~> 3.0.0) ruby

    builder (3.1.4)`

Comment: Delete `Gemfile.lock` then rerun `bundle update`

Comment: I tried that again, here's what I got: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "builder":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (~> 0.7.0) ruby depends on
      builder (~> 3.0.0) ruby

    builder (3.1.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bson":
  In Gemfile:
    bson_ext (~> 1.5) ruby depends on
      bson (= 1.5.2) ruby

    mongo (= 1.6.2) ruby depends on
      bson (1.6.2)`

Comment: If you delete all versioning in your gems, bundle should be able to work this out. Did you try that?

Comment: Just tried that as well; no dice :-\.

Comment: if you use the spermy operator you want to limit it to `3` or `3.0` and not more than that otherwise it`s like `=`. Also try adding `http://rubygems.org` as the single source.

Answer (score 3):

Happens mostly because `Mongoid` ( >3.0 is what I've had this error with ) has a dependency of `active_model ~> 3.1` gem which inturn has a dependency on `builder ~> 3.1`. Remove the `builder` entry in your Gemfile, delete `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle`.